# How to skip line which is starting from '#' while reading a file in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I need to skip those lines which are starting from # while reading from a file.

### input.txt

```
aaaaa
abababa
#acdef 
cabef 
#a
```

Below is the program which I have written,

### RaviSirI_OQstn1Assignment.java

```
package mypack;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class RaviSirI_OQstn1Assignment {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bip = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("F:\\javaAdarsh\\input.txt"));

            int i;
            long l = 1;
            int p = bip.available();
            System.out.println(p);
            while((i= bip.read())!=-1) {
                 if((char)i=='#') {
                     bip.skip(8);
                 }
                 else
                    System.out.print((char)i);
             }
             System.out.println("");
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("error");
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: and your problem is ?

Comment: 1st I would change to an `BufferedReader` since reading text and not binary/bytes; 2nd I would read lines, `BuffredReader` should have such method; 3rd I would use `startsWith` method (or just check 1st character of line)

Comment: so you're asking for ready code without doing any attempts. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You skip 8 bytes when you encounter a `#` char.  It is not what you want. What you want is going to the next line. So you should loop while you don't find a new line char.  But that is rather cumbersome as approach.
In fact, you don't use the right API. `BufferedReader.readLine()` would be more simpler.
It returns a String that represents the line content. So you just need to compare the fist char of it with `#` to know if you need to ignore the line content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `BufferedReader`, which then would allow you to read the file one line at a time:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = 
    Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("F:\\javaAdarsh\\input.txt"))
) {

    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.matches("#.*")) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

When reading by line, we only need to apply the regex pattern `^#.*` to catch any line beginning with a `#`.

Comment: `DataInput...` mostly for reading primitives (and **modified** UTF-8); `...InputStream` mostly for reading binary (stream of bytes); `...Reader` for reading text (character streams) - and kind of overkill to use regex to test if a string starts with a given character

Comment: BTW: "**Deprecated**.
This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK **1.1**, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method."

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Answer updated.  I'm old :-)